# Is this a valid correlated sub query with joins?

Tags: sql, postgresql, correlated-subquery

So I have a table `Car(Car_id, Value, Make)`, another table `Person(Person_id, Name)` and a third table linking the two together `PerCar(Car_id, Person_id)`.

So I have this correlated subquery:

```
SELECT MAKE, VALUE 
FROM CAR WHERE VALUE > (SELECT AVG(VALUE) FROM CAR C WHERE C.CAR_ID = CAR_ID);
```

So if I wanted to display the person's name also, is this also valid correlated sub query:

```
SELECT Car.Make, Car.Value, Person.Name 
FROM PerCar NATURAL JOIN Car 
NATURAL JOIN Person where Car.Value > (SELECT AVG(VALUE) FROM Car);
```

Comment: Your two queries return different results, #1 is a Correlated Subquery returning rows with a value grater than the average value of the correlated CAR_ID But 2# returns rows with a value greater than the average value of *all* cars, it's not correlated, it's *Scalar*

Comment: In fact, your 1st Select is not a Correlated Subquery because there's no corelation between inner and outer table, `WHERE C.CAR_ID = CAR_ID` is the same as `1=1`, should be `FROM CAR C WHERE VALUE > (SELECT AVG(VALUE) FROM CAR C2 WHERE C.CAR_ID = C2.CAR_ID)`

Comment: Avoid natural joins like the plague.

Answer (score 0):

Your query should be as below-

You can check [DEMO HERE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=bb7174d408b70c7edc11c4138080745d)

```
SELECT Car.Make, 
Car.Value, 
Person.Name 
from Car
INNER JOIN CarPer 
    ON Car.Car_id = CarPer.Car_id 
INNER JOIN Person
    ON Person.Person_id = CarPer.Person_ID        
WHERE Car.Value > (SELECT AVG(VALUE) FROM Car);
```

Remember, here joining can be INNER, OUTER, LEFT or other joins based on your requirement and data structure.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for that, I have been given an extra table called ```PerCar(Car_id, Person_id) which links the Car table and Person table together. So can I not do 3 joins, one like ```Car Inner Join PerCar Inner Join Person```? Would this still be a correlated sub query?

Comment: and this would still be a valid Correlated Sub query?

Comment: Yes, this is valid.

Comment: thats great thanks, I was told in :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59120948/correlated-subquery-natural-joins?noredirect=1#comment104472351_59120948 that correlated query's cant have joins.

Comment: Well, there's no *Correlated* Subquery, it's a *Scalar* Subquery

Comment: You have joins on your main query here. And using sub query just to filter out rows from your main query. So this is fine as query syntax. For reference, please check the same query written in fiddle- https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=bb7174d408b70c7edc11c4138080745d

Comment: @dnoeth Okay, so I cant make a correlated sub query where I want to display the Person's Name?

Comment: @Drakus: Of course, you can; `from Car AS C
INNER JOIN ....        
WHERE Car.Value > (SELECT AVG(VALUE) FROM Car AS C2 WHERE C.CAR_ID = C2.CAR_ID)`

Answer (score 0):

This is NOT a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT MAKE, VALUE 
FROM CAR
WHERE VALUE > (SELECT AVG(VALUE) FROM CAR C WHERE C.CAR_ID = CAR_ID);
```

**Always qualify all column references in a query.**

You *think* the `WHERE` clause is:

```
WHERE CAR.VALUE > (SELECT AVG(VALUE) FROM CAR C WHERE C.CAR_ID = CAR.CAR_ID);
```

But it is really:

```
WHERE CAR.VALUE > (SELECT AVG(C.VALUE) FROM CAR C WHERE C.CAR_ID = C.CAR_ID);
```

There is no reference to the outer query, so this is not correlated.  I would write this as:

```
SELECT C.MAKE, C.VALUE 
FROM CAR C
WHERE C.VALUE > (SELECT AVG(C2.VALUE) FROM CAR C2 WHERE C2.CAR_ID = C2.CAR_ID);
```

However, it is unlikely that this will return any rows.  Given your lack of problem statement and the values in your tables, a sensible query would return "all cars whose value is higher than the average for their make"

```
SELECT C.MAKE, C.VALUE 
FROM CAR C
WHERE C.VALUE > (SELECT AVG(C2.VALUE) FROM CAR C2 WHERE C2.MAKE = C.MAKE);
```

Because the rest of your question is predicated on the first query being a "correlated subquery", the rest of the question does not make sense.

Comment: I guess `WHERE C2.CAR_ID = C2.CAR_ID` should be `WHERE C2.CAR_ID = C.CAR_ID` ??

Comment: What you call 'column references' are actually range variables and represent rows i.e. wrong mindset. Note that using `NATURAL JOIN` does away with the need for range variables e.g. the OP's second query could be written `SELECT Make, Value, Name... WHERE Value...` ? i.e. remove the redundant range variables.

Comment: @onedaywhen . . . `NATURAL JOIN` is an abomination because it does not take properly declared foreign key relationships into account.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: repeat after me: SQL DML (including join) does not rely on SQL DDL (including fks) *by design*.